# How can I use MimeMessageHelper to send HTML template emails?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, html-email, mime-message

How do I alter below code to send emails with body as HTML templates? What I tried was changing `mimeMessageHelper.setText()` method to `mimeMessageHelper.setContent()` and apparently that doesn't work. I'd like to know if anyone can share some insight on how to do this.

```
private void sendEmailAndUpdateCount(EmailContent emailContent, JavaMailSender mailSender) {
    System.out.println(emailContent.toString());
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

    try {
        MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);

        mimeMessageHelper.setSubject(emailContent.getSubject());
        mimeMessageHelper.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail, fromEmailName));
        mimeMessageHelper.setTo(emailContent.getToRecipients().get(0));
        mimeMessageHelper.setText(emailContent.getBody());
        mimeMessageHelper.addAttachment("Invoice - " + emailContent.getAttachmentName(), new File(emailContent.getAttachment()));

        mailSender.send(mimeMessageHelper.getMimeMessage());

    } catch (MessagingException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    progressCount.getAndIncrement();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setText` recieves 2nd argument, `boolean html`.
Also, call `mimeMessage.saveChanges()` before the `send`, it might help.

Comment: Is there a method called `saveChanges()` in mimeMessageHelper? I get an error message as "Cannot resolve method saveChanges() in mimeMessageHelper".

Comment: you're right, my typo. It's on the MimeMessage.

Comment: There is an overloaded version of `setText` that takes a plain text body AND an html body. Which one gets rendered is, I think, down to the email client.